# If someone becomes gravely ill and their name is changed in Shul, is their name also changed on their Kesubah?

Tags: halacha, marriage, ketubah, legal-documents

A source: https://outorah.org/p/119405/

When someone becomes gravely ill and their name is changed in order to aid in their refuah, is their name also altered on their Kesubah?

Comment: The question is answered in your link.

Comment: @shmosel thank you, apologies, for everyone else: _The new name is to be used in all documents, such as a ketuba upon marriage and a get in the event of a divorce. [Rema, EH 129:18; Pitchei Teshuva, EH 129:53,54] Indeed, some authorities advise those who are married to rewrite their ketuba with their new name, while others are not particular to do so. [Minchat Yitzchak 10:132]_

Comment: The question might be, then: what about their (already married) children - according to the authorities who say that the recovered person should change his kesubah, should his children do the same?

Comment: No! We don't go back and edit documents! Documents are dated, so we could check "what was that person's name as of that date?" (Just as "what was the name of the town at that date?".) It just meant *for any future documents* ....

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Akiva and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @Shalom I'm not sure Meir meant edit, but rewrite, as per the preceding comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lifted from the source I quoted ([Shinui Shem: Changing the Name of One Who is Ill](https://outorah.org/p/119405/)):

> The new name is to be used in all documents, such as a ketuba upon
> marriage and a get in the event of a divorce. [Rema, EH 129:18;
> Pitchei Teshuva, EH 129:53,54] Indeed, some authorities advise those
> who are married to rewrite their ketuba with their new name, while
> others are not particular to do so. [Minchat Yitzchak 10:132]